# How to remove extra space in navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

Okay I am making a navigation bar and I pretty much did it well but one thing bothers me and that is how to get rid of the little space that lies in between first li and left margin.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
       <a href="#">Resume</a></li><li>
       <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav {margin:0px;padding:0px;}
#nav ul {list-style-type:none;background: #909909;}
#nav ul li {display: inline-table;padding: 10px;margin: 0px;}
#nav ul li:hover {background-color:#333;}
#nav ul li a {text-decoration: none;font-family:klavika;color: #fff;}
```

**My problem's screen capture :**

[image: Navigation Bar]

As you can see the space between that first li element and the left margin.

Comment: remove the UL padding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kill the left padding on the `ul`:

```
#nav ul {list-style-type:none; background:#909909; padding-left:0;}
```

Comment: thank you! now i know but didnt knew then !!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this?

The Element takes 40 pixels padding from left. If we have giving the value that will be overwrite.

```
#nav ul {padding-left: 0px;}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks man its solved now and it was such a silly mistake :) !!